# no routes matched location using react router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

Okay so I'm trying to build an app which consists of 2 pages, home page and a designer page. The app takes a user input value which would be a certain (url) and on clicking the navigate button in the home page, it should redirects the user from the home page to the designer page and pass this url to the designer component. The designer component should use this url to pass it to a custom hook for fetching data using my own API and then render the data in a drop-down-list. I already tested the endpoints and it works fine but the problem is that each time i try to enter the url and hit navigate it gives me an error saying that No routes matched location ./designer/"url" but if I tried to enter it in the browser itself it redirects me to the designer page and renders it fine, so I don't know what is the problem actually.

`**App.jsx **`

```
import React from "react"
import AppRouter from './Components/AppRouter'

function App() {
  return (
      <div>
        <AppRouter />
      </div>
  );
 };

export default App;
```

`**AppRouter.jsx **`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import TemplateSelector from "./TemplateSelector";

class AppRouter extends Component {
  render() {
     return (
        <BrowserRouter>
           <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
              <Route path="designer/:url" element={<TemplateSelector />} />
           </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      );
     }
    }

 export default AppRouter;
```

`**Home.jsx **`

```
 import React, { useState } from "react";
 import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
 import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";

   function Home() {
      const [url, setURL] = useState('');
      return (
           <div className="py-5 container">
             <Form>
               <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1" value = {url}
                 onChange={(e) => setURL(e.target.value)}>
                 <Form.Label>URL</Form.Label>
                 <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="example.com" />
               </Form.Group>
             </Form>
               <Link className="btn btn-primary btn-sm" to={`designer/${url}`}>
                   navigate
               </Link>
           </div>
        );
     }

     export default Home;
```

`**TemplateSelector.jsx **`

```
   import React, { useState } from "react";
   import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
   import { Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
   import getTemplates from "../Hooks/getTemplates";
   import Designer from "./Designer";

   function TemplateSelector() {
       const [showDesigner, setShowDesigner] = useState(false)
       const onClick = () => setShowDesigner(true)
       const {url} = useParams();
       const data = getTemplates(url);   // this line is for calling the custom hook
       const templates = data.Templates;   // this is the response properties
       const parameters = data.Parameters;  // this is the response properties

       return(
             <div className = "py-1 container">
                  <h1>Designer</h1>
                <Form className="py-1 container">
                    <option>Select a Template</option>
                   <Form.Select className="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" onChange={() => onClick()}>
                    {templates.map((t) => (
                    <option key={t.Id}>{t.TemplateName}</option>
                    ))}
                </Form.Select>
            </Form>
        <div>
            { showDesigner ? <Designer designerURL={url} name="user" parameters={parameters} /> : null }
        </div>
    </div>
   );
};

 export default TemplateSelector;
```

`**Designer.jsx **`

```
import React from "react";

function Designer(props) {
     return(
         <div className="Generator">
            <br/>
           Hi This is a test for {props.name} to see the {props.designerURL} and the {parameters}.
   </div>
   );
};

  export default Designer;`
```

Comment: *When* exactly during this UI flow do you get this "No routes matched" error? What sort of `url` values are being entered? What is the URL path that works when manually navigating to the designer route?

Comment: FWIW I'm unable to reproduce any specific issue you describe using your code in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/no-routes-matched-location-using-react-router-v6-ee2st7?file=/src/App.js:171-219). The routing and navigation appears to work as I'd expect it to. Feel free to fork this sandbox to see if you can create a version that reproduces any issue that we could then inspect live.